# Cannot Add Class to AutoComplete ul il list and cannot focus on li list element when press on down arrow key (Not using jquery UI)

Tags: jquery

Cannot Add Class   to AutoComplete ul il list  and cannot focus on li list element  when press on down arrow key  (Not using jquery UI)

```
<div id ="autodiv" style='position:relative'>        
                                    <input type="text" id ="autofill" /> 
                                    <div id= "autoCompletelist" style="max-height:150px;overflow-y:scroll;position:absolute;width:auto"></div>

                                </div>
```

here is also my jquery code also to show ajax and key down event

```
 $(document).on('keyup', '#autofill' ,function(e)
{
    var that = $(this);
    var autotext = $(this).val(); 
    //$('#fillAutofill li').remove();
    //alert(autotext);
    $.ajax({
        url:'xxxxxxxtestautofill.php',
        method:'POST',
        data:{autotext:autotext},

        success:function(data)
        {
            $('#autoCompletelist').fadeIn('slow');
            $('#autoCompletelist').html(data);


        },
        error:function(data)
        {
            alert('something wrong ');
        }

    });




    var currntFocus = -1;
    if (e.keyCode  == 40 )
    {

        currntFocus++;
        $('#autoCompletelist').find('li:eq('+currntFocus+')').focus().addClass('fff');

    }



});

$(document).on('click', '#autoCompletelist li' ,function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#autofill').val($(this).text());

    $('#autoCompletelist').fadeOut('fast');


});
```

> here is also my jquery code also to show ajax and key down event